# Why Micronaut is sending connection: close even for > 499?

Tags: micronaut

Why Micronaut is sending connection: close even for > 499. The connection isn't bad and can be reused regardless even if the response was 5xx???
Can we have some potential feature flag or some alternative to not invoke this behaviour? Is there any issue if we bypass this logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you answered your own question https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/5552